# What are those _compiler arguments good for? _compiler(_element.childNodes, _directiveMap)(_injector, _element.childNodes)

Tags: angularjs, dart, angular-dart

I need help in understanding dart-code that I successfully use. 
(Details: I use it to inject SVG graphics containing bindings to variable CSS classes)

- Can I call the constructor arguments here "injected dependencies"?
- What is inside of these arguments: this._injector, this._compiler, this._directiveMap
- How are those parts working together using _compiler(...) ?

I found this explanation but it is not covering the whole story: https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/compiler

The code:

```
@Decorator(
  selector: '[bindHtml]'
)
class BindHtml {
  static dom.NodeValidator validator;

  dom.Element _element;
  Compiler _compiler;
  Injector _injector;
  DirectiveMap _directiveMap;

  BindHtml(this._element, this._injector, this._compiler, this._directiveMap) {
    validator = new AllowAllValidator();
  }

  @NgOneWay('bindHtml')
  set value(value) {
    if(value == null) {
      _element.nodes.clear();
      return;
    }
    String givenHTML = _element.innerHtml;
    value = value+= givenHTML;
    _element.setInnerHtml((value == null ? '' : value.toString()), validator: validator);
    if(value != null) {
      _compiler(_element.childNodes, _directiveMap)(_injector, _element.childNodes);
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First off, realize that the API for `Compiler` and `ViewFactory` have changed in AngularDart 0.13.0.  It looks like you are using the old APIs and should move to the new APIs instead.

Second, your `bindHtml` directive is very similar to the core `ng-include` directive.  Consider using it instead.

Third, access the `Compiler` and `ViewFactory` directly is considered advanced usage -- you are getting into parts of Angular where the APIs are not very stable nor well-documented.  I don't fully understand your use-cases, but there is most likely a way to implement your solution without accessing the `Compiler`.

That said, I'll dig into your questions:

1. Yes. The constructor arguments are all injected.  Your directive will get instances of the `Compiler`, `Element`, etc from the dependency injection system.  Since the injection system follows the structure of the DOM, you will get the `Element` on which this `@Decorator` is defined, but a global singleton `Compiler`.

   Note, that in 0.13.0, directives (decorators, components) will want to inject the `DirectiveInjector` instead.  That injector is optimized for directives and being created for each DOM node.
2. (and 3) The compiler takes a list of DOM nodes and a `DirectiveMap` and produces a `ViewFactory`.  It will iterate over the DOM nodes creating "`ElementBinder`s" which contain instructions on what directives to create at which nodes.  This information is stored over multiple instantiates of the same `View`.  Angular has a `ViewCache` which is used to avoid calling `Compiler` over and over.

   The `DirectiveMap` is passed in so we can use different directives at different points in the app.  I think this is a [bug](https://github.com/angular/angular.dart/issues/1087) and should not be included in the API.

   The `ViewFactory` then takes a `Scope`, injector and optionally already-created DOM nodes and builds the `View` which is the actual DOM nodes on the page.  (Again, this API has changes in 0.13.0)

Comment: Thank you. We use AngularDart 0.12.0 right now. ng-include seems to be not exactly what we are looking for because we indeed load content from an url but we enhance the code before compiling and injecting it into the dom. Two more questions: 1. The _compiler needs _injector for potential dependencies in the _element.childNodes? How and why two brackets after _compiler(..)(..)?

Comment: What do I have to fear reading this: "inherently dangerous" (mhevery commented on 19 Mar) @ https://github.com/angular/angular.dart/issues/742 ? I look at that code as client side code and would never trust the output on servers side. That is why I don't fear code injection using this code. Is there a CSRF vulnerability or something like that, I should be aware of?

Comment: The two brackets: The ``Compiler`` produces a ``ViewFactory``, that is the first bracket.  The ``ViewFactory`` can be reused to produce ``View``s as needed.  It is the ``ViewFactory`` that needs the ``Injector`` to get instances of directives.  ------- The dangerous part, yes it is a CSRF/XSRF risk if you are including user input in the template string.